# Exposing blocking API in golang?

Tags: api-design, protocol, golang

I have a golang library that abstracts a network service (think IRC-alike). The network server produces events which users of my library should consume. I'm using blocking network calls internally. I want to design my API to minimise friction users of my library, so i'm trying to decide between

- having the user supply `func` callbacks to `mylib.doStuff()`, which would enter my library's blocking network loop; it would be up to the caller to background this into a goroutine if they wished (and then perform their own synchronisation as necessary); or
- having the user call `mylib.startDoingStuff()`, which would spawn a background goroutine to handle the blocking network calls, returning multiple channels of events for the caller to `select` over. It has the advantage of isolating the goroutine and the blocking from the calling code.

What's more idiomatic? What would you expect to see in a network library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a resource on the topic:

- https://inconshreveable.com/07-08-2014/principles-of-designing-go-apis-with-channels/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2acr79/principles_of_designing_go_apis_with_channels/

In the end, i'm convinced a channel-based API is probably the way forward (at least for a v1 package), following the example of stdlib `crypto/ssh`.

However, the above link did strongly caution against implementing a channel-based API, mentioning a range of pitfalls (adequately describing buffer limits, edge case behavior, exhaustion behavior and so on)

Comment: No, channel-based API is not a way to Go. It depends. Try to use your package and decide which one is easier to use: callback or channels etc.